# Check Grammar of a sentence using Parse score given by Stanford parser

Tags: java, parsing, nlp, grammar, stanford-nlp

I am able to parse a sentence and get the parse score using Stanford parser with the java code below

```
LexicalizedParser lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel(
    "edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz"
);

lp.setOptionFlags(new String[]{"-maxLength", "80", "-retainTmpSubcategories"});

String sent = "My name is Rahul";
Tree parse = (Tree) lp.apply(sent);
double score = parse.score();
```

Is there any way to check the grammaticality of a sentence using this parse score given by Stanford parser?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In contrast to @kutschkem, I'd say the answer is not a hard 'no', but a very cautious 'maybe'. This is definitely an active area of research. I've seen (unpublished) work indicating that length-normalized parse scores (inside probabilities) demonstrated a bimodal distribution, with the manually-annotated 'worse' sentences generally falling into the lower peak, and the 'better' sentences into the higher. That was for one specific corpus (of Tweets, if I recall correctly), and I don't know if it's been replicated elsewhere.

More generally, syntactic parse information can be quite helpful in classifying grammaticality, but probably not as the only classification feature. You might look at some of the work of Joel Tetrault and the research team he worked with at ETS. Jennifer Foster at Dublin has also done some work in this area. Their papers (and their bibliographies) should get you started.

But (unfortunately) building a useful classifier will not be as easy as just extracting the inside parse scores.

Comment: Are there any changes in the recent CoreNLP versions that support this feature?

Answer (score 1):

So your question is whether you can check that the sentence is grammatically correct? The answer is no. As an example, i once tried generating question by simple word substitution and comparing the parse scores of all permutations of the words. (I know, the approach is bad, but serves as a good example). The problem was, however, that sentences that did not make sense (i'm not completely sure about grammaticality) got ranked higher than any of the permutations that were actually questions. Seeing that questions are probably rare in the corpus used to train the language model, one can expect such behavior.
If you have a low score, it just means your sentence has an uncommon structure, not that it is grammatically incorrect. Actually, grammatically incorrect sentences should not get parsed at all. Be honest, there is only few that is really grammatically incorrect.

Btw. "My Rahul is name" is also grammatically correct ;-)  (ok fine, depends on your grammar)